# Tomcat doesn't work on specific directory

Tags: jsp, tomcat, javabeans

I have developed a webpage with JSP.

During development, I used the address `http://myhomepage.com/~dev/` and it works.

After I copied all the files from the directory (`/var/www/~dev/`) to the root directory(`/var/www/`), JSP files occurs errors when I open `http://myhomepage.com/` . The error message is like:

> HTTP Status 500 - /a.jsp (line: 5, column: 0) The value for the useBean class attribute TestBean is invalid.

#### My environment:

OS: Linux(Debian) 
Server: Apache2 + Tomcat8

Answer (score 1):

When you use useBean jsp tag you should specify FQCN.

```
<jsp:useBean id="test" 
                class="com.myhomepage.TestBean ">
```

See examples of [jsp:useBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnair.html) tag usage in the java tutorial

> **Creating and Using a JavaBeans Component**
>
> To declare that your JSP page will use a JavaBeans component, you use
>   a jsp:useBean element. There are two forms:
>
> ```
> <jsp:useBean id="beanName"
>     class="fully-qualified-classname" scope="scope"/>
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> <jsp:useBean id="beanName"
>     class="fully-qualified-classname" scope="scope">
>     <jsp:setProperty .../>
> </jsp:useBean>
> ```
>
> The second form is used when you want to include jsp:setProperty
>   statements, described in the next section, for initializing bean
>   properties.
>
> The jsp:useBean element declares that the page will use a bean that is
>   stored within and is accessible from the specified scope, which can be
>   application, session, request, or page. If no such bean exists, the
>   statement creates the bean and stores it as an attribute of the scope
>   object (see Using Scope Objects). The value of the id attribute
>   determines the name of the bean in the scope and the identifier used
>   to reference the bean in EL expressions, other JSP elements, and
>   scripting expressions (see Chapter 9, Scripting in JSP Pages). The
>   value supplied for the class attribute must be a fully qualified class
>   name. Note that beans cannot be in the unnamed package. Thus the
>   format of the value must be package-name.class-name.

Comment: I reduced my classname at the question, but I am actually using FQCN. And the same code works at the different directory.